# How to include white spaces in my file reading

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
int main()
{
string path = "c:\\encryption\\";
string searchPattern = "*.txt";
string fullSearchPath = path + searchPattern;

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFile( fullSearchPath.c_str(), &FindData );

if( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    cout << " !!! Error searching directory !!!" << endl;;
    return -1;
}

do
{
    string filePath = path + FindData.cFileName;
    ifstream in( filePath.c_str() );
    if( in )
    {
       //////////////////////// HERE IS PROBLEM I KNOW THAT BUT WHAT I DON'T KNOW
                char s;
                while (!in.eof()) 
                { 
                    in >> s; 
                    cout << s << endl; 
                }

                cout << "************************ File Completely Read *** **************************** " << endl;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " !!! Problem opening file !!!" << FindData.cFileName << "\n";
    }
}
while( FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData) > 0 );

if( GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES )
{
    cout << " !!! Something went wrong during searching !!! " << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

**I am reading all the files from a specific folder one by one  And then
for each file reading it character by character.. Above is my effort
so far Now, I am stuck in a part that i want to read white spaces as
well.. What should i do ? what should i include? Kindly give me some suggestions**

Comment: Use `get` rather than `>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>>` and `<<` operators are designed for **formatted** operations, while you need **binary** operations. Try opening the stream with `ios::binary`:

```
ifstream in( filePath.c_str(), ios::binary );
```

and using `read` (or `readsome`) and `write` to handle I/O.

If you want to stick with formatted operations (which you shouldn't if you`re into encryption), use `getline` to read lines containing whitespace characters;

Comment: O.k I included binary stream to my code.. But nothing has happened. The results are still the same..

Comment: Because you still use operators `>>` and `<<`.

Comment: what is the syntax for read or readsome and the purpse of these ?? Can you explain in some major detail please?

Comment: Just click on the function names in my post. They're links to cplusplus.com.

Comment: More Specifically on RSA algorithm. That is why i need to read files character by character including spaces

Answer (score 1):

use the getline() methood to get charater and space
thats and efficent way.